# How to get original file from diff output?

Tags: linux, memory-management

I want to save my memory space by saving the diff output of hundreds of files with main file which are very similar to main file.
I would like to know a way to get the original files from diff output and main file.
If there is a single command I would be pleased but other answers will also do.

Thanks..

Comment: What is memory space? Disk space? Disk space is very cheap.

Comment: You need the `patch` program. Basic usage is `patch old_file <diff1234.txt` There are options/flags for recursive usage, etc.